# Como puedo deshacer mi ultimo commit en Git?

Tags: git

Hice commit al archivo equivocado. no he hecho push del commit al servidor.

Como puedo deshacer esos commits?

Answer (score 1):

Podes hacerlo mediante el comando `git reset HEAD~` o `git reset HEAD~1` que te permite pasar los cambios del último commit al área de trabajo. `HEAD~` significa que retroceda en una posición con respecto al último commit (`HEAD`).

Answer (score 0):

```
git revert HEAD
```

No borra el commit, crea uno nuevo donde se revierte ultimo commit hecho.